# Carpet under framing 2x4 exterior wall ,the carpet got wet and needs to be pulled out ,do I need to support each area under bottom plate stud

Tags: moisture, carpet, timber-framing

Framing of wall over carpet and pad ,carpet and pad got wet and cannot be dried properly so we need to remove the carpet and pad under the bottom plate studs,do I have to brace the bottom plate studs while grinding out the carpet and pad under the bottom plate studs or can I leave it be without any structural hard ,it is an exterior wall, or should I pack out the area or shim area of we’re carpet is removed ?

Comment: Is the 2x4 wall up against an outside wall or is it the outside wall?  The carpet is probably has nails though it also, most walls are nailed to the floor, but I would not assume that in this case.

Comment: If you really have carpet underneath the plate of an exterior wall, just cut the carpet back, leave some under the plate, and let it dry naturally. It won’t be quick, but it’ll happen, just as wet wood dries naturally.

Comment: How the heck did you get carpet under a load-bearing wall?

Comment: someone was really really against furring strips.